# Using Dart to check if HTML5 API is available in browser

Tags: html, dart

How can I check if a specific `HTML5 API` is available in the browser ?

For example, in `JavaScript`

```
if(!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
```

What is the equivalent in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:html';
...
SpeechRecognition.supported
```

see also https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/tests/html/speechrecognition_test.dart